# OpenRefine delete empty rows

Tags: excel, openrefine

I want to delete empty rows in OntotextRefine, which is the same as OpenRefine.

Hello, my csv file opened into ontotextrefine (same as open refine) but made every other row blank. If I try "delete matching rows" it deletes every single row. The csv file doesn't appear to be the problem. What can I try? Thank you[image: ontotext][image: csv file]

Comment: My guess is that OntotextRefine did not automatically grasp the format. Try creating the project again and change the parsing options in the project preview to CSV, use comma as separator and so on... The preview should give you live a feedback on your actions.

Comment: For support of a proprietary app, you are best off asking your vendor's support channel (and this isn't really a programming question).

Answer (score 0):

In OpenRefine you would do the following:

1. Use the ["Facet by blank"](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/facets#facet-by-null-empty-or-blank) on a column which will only be blank in the rows you want to remove
2. Choose the 'true' value in that facet - this should filter your project to show only the rows where the selected column is blank
3. Click the dropdown menu at the top of the 'All' column and choose Edit rows -> Remove  matching rows

Note this does rely on the cells that show as empty in your screenshot actually being empty - if they (for example) are populated with whitespace characters, then they aren't going to be shown as 'blank'. You can try to [Trim leading and trailing whitespace](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace) before the steps described above if this is the case.

If none of this works then I'd suggest either raising an issue with OntoTextRefine or asking on the [OpenRefine forum](https://forum.openrefine.org)